# html2canvas jspdf with next js pdf view error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jspdf, html2canvas

i use html2canvas jspdf with nextjs. now i generate pdf but generated pdf look is wrong. h1 tag view looklike p tag. i need fix it. i need generate only html view to pdf. i need only this module use.please help me

[PDF Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuWmA.png)

```
"use client";
import { useRef } from "react";
import jsPDF from "jspdf";
import html2canvas from "html2canvas";

export default function Pdf() {
  const reportTemplateRef = useRef(null);
  const handleDownloadPdf = async () => {
    const element = reportTemplateRef.current;
    if (element) {
      const canvas = await html2canvas(element);
      const data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

      const pdf = new jsPDF("l", "pt", "a4");
      pdf.html(document.getElementById("testing"), {
        callback: function () {
          pdf.save("print.pdf");
        },
      });
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={reportTemplateRef} id="testing" className="view">
      <h1>hello world</h1>
      <h2>hello woerld</h2>
      <h3>hello world</h3>
      <h4>hello world</h4>
      <h5>hello world</h5>
      <h6>hello world</h6>
      <br />
      <p>
        hello world Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Quis voluptate laboriosam odit tempora impedit ab, veritatis repellendus
        aut! Molestiae nostrum cum dolores vitae, minus veniam alias architecto
        maiores officia dignissimos.
      </p>
      </div>
      <div className="button">
        <button onClick={handleDownloadPdf}>Download</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Generated pdf view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvbic.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the display of the `h1` tag, add CSS to `h1`:

```
<h1 style={{ fontSize: '50px' }}>hello world</h1>
```

Comment: i uploaded image. styles are not work. please can you check image link below the code?

Comment: have you tried addHTML? pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById("testing"), {
        callback: function () {
          pdf.save("print.pdf");
        },
      });